# Why does conditional type inference in Typescript cause the type in my unref implementation to be classified as unknown?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, conditional-types

I have implemented 2 versions of the Vuejs function "unref".
This has one parameter which can be of type `Ref<T>:{ value: T }` or anything else. 
If the parameter gets a Ref unref or unref2 returns the Ref.value otherwise it simply returns the parameter.
The only difference between the functions is how I use the Typescript syntax.
Why does Typescript has an issue with the unref2 function?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShBmAeAagQwDYFcID4oF4oBvKANw2wC4o0toBfAbgChmB6N2CYTAJwDsAzlGAALaKEhQA9vC5IAKuAgB5eHHh4AlnK3BhqeVAjpB0Xtz78oC5pOgBxbkshqAsqhAAjCBsQK8QgVjAA9gCH4AE2E-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-cIwgI0MmmosjmCAA)

```
type Ref<Value> = { value: Value };

// Returns the type of Ref<TypeOfRef> if its a Ref else return T
type GetTypeOfMaybeRef<T> = T extends Ref<infer V> ? V : T;

// works
function unref<T>(maybeRef: Ref<GetTypeOfMaybeRef<T>>|GetTypeOfMaybeRef<T>): GetTypeOfMaybeRef<T> {
    if (maybeRef != null && typeof maybeRef === 'object' && "value" in maybeRef) {
        return maybeRef.value;
    } else {
        return maybeRef;
    }
}

// does not work, why?
// should be like unref.
// I know, T is just T.
// I did it to give ts a hint that T can be a Ref.
function unref2<T>(maybeRef: T extends Ref<infer Value> ? Ref<Value> : T): GetTypeOfMaybeRef<T> {
    if (maybeRef != null && typeof maybeRef === 'object' && "value" in maybeRef) {
        return maybeRef.value;
    } else {
        // why ts error? 
        // should it not be the same as unref?
        return maybeRef;
    }
}


const ref: Ref<number> = { value: 3 };
const numRef: Ref<number> = { value: 3 };
const num = unref(numRef)
const strRef: Ref<string> = { value: "blalba" };
const text = unref(strRef)
```

Comment: Inside the body of `unref2()`, `GetTypeOfMaybeRef<T>` is a *generic conditional type*.  As such, the compiler really can't verify that some specific value is of that type.  You can't do checks on `maybeRef` to narrow `T`, which is a current limitation or missing feature; see [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), so that's why `unref2` doesn't work. The reason `unref` works is because either `maybeRef` or `maybeRef.value` is already of type `GetTypeOfMaybeRef<T>`. Does this fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: ah ok, so it's not smart enough to realize that the types end up being the same.
Do you know a source which explains how typescript type interference exactly works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deriving a generic type from an argument that has a conditional type is going to hit and miss. Sometimes Typescript can figure out simple cases, but when it gets complicated things will start to fail.

It's best to avoid that situation altogether.

---

That said, You are trying *very* hard here, and this can be much simpler:

```
type Ref<Value> = { value: Value };

function unref<T>(maybeRef: Ref<T> | T): T {
    if (maybeRef != null && typeof maybeRef === 'object' && "value" in maybeRef) {
        return maybeRef.value;
    } else {
        return maybeRef;
    }
}
```

There is no `infer` or even any conditional types required. `unref` takes either a `Ref<T> | T` and `T` is returned. Easy peasy.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShBmAeAagQwDYFcID4oF4oBvKANw2wC4o0toBfAbgChn5MA7AY2AEsB7DlE4AnBIgAqOABQBbVCABGEOPGqrJeAD5QJASmoTizKKai94UOQuWqoAQkIdM6dFABk7qKEj9L8pRUEAnxCAHJ+RQArCB4wjy8AInI6RPMhANsEPWMzPKgxYEwRDJsg+AA6FOwWPPooCHQAZ2giE3zTQuLSwNVas3pmQeYuQSbgAoR1cWdZZRE8QhJqiGoAZigmEbGJ2dVppFn5xeIyClWoDa3RjnGoWYJhDjF4aT3s7duJ8ZF92HEfrwOABzE7Lc7URKKdAYRSoNLXHbeCAADwmhFECGkP1UemYQA)

---

And if you need `GetTypeOfMaybeRef<T>` still then you can do that without `infer`:

```
type GetTypeOfMaybeRef<T> = T extends Ref<unknown> ? T['value'] : T;

type A = GetTypeOfMaybeRef<{ value: number }> // number
type B = GetTypeOfMaybeRef<string> // string
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShBmAeAagQwDYFcID4oF4oBvKANw2wC4o0toBfAbgChnRIoBxCYAFXAgB5eAFlUIAEYQ4SXnkK8oEAB7AIAOwAmAZ1gJEmdQGt1AewDu6vAH4ovANoBycnUcBdKNV4s2AqAEECLh5+SGExSWl9EhcqKHVMAFspACcoejwAekz4pNTfDgAhIO4+AXDxKRlEbWAUgEt1AHMsnNqG5qA)

Comment: thanks, i asumed he does:
T = Ref<number> that would result to:
function unref(maybeRef: Ref< Ref<number>> |  Ref<number>):  Ref<number>;
How does the ts interference exactly works?
I have read the docu but .... didnt see it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Why would you do `Ref<Ref<number>>`?

Comment: I assumed T is just a placeholder. I thought that he takes Ref<number> and replaces T. Do u know a source which describes how TS generics are resolved?